# Table with style"width=100%" cause different result in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is the code:

it works well in Firefox and Opera, however it does not in IE:

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style>
                body {
                    border: 1px solid gray;
                    line-height: 120%;
                    margin: 5px;
                    width:100%;
                }
                
                h1#header,h5#footer {
                    background-color: gray;
                    clear: both;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                
                div#menu {
                    width: 190px;
                    float: left;
                }
                
                div#body {
                    margin-left: 200px;
                    padding: 2px;
                    border-left: 2px gray solid;
                }
                
                table {
                    border: 1px solid #CEDCED;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    margin: 2px auto;
                    width: 100%;
                }
                
                th {
                    border: 2px ridge maroon;
                    background-color: maroon;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 2px;
                }
                
                tr {
                    background-color: white;
                    margin: 1px;
                }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function setTableWidth(){
                    alert(document.getElementById('tab').offsetWidth);
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload=setTableWidth()>

        <h1 id="header">Header</h1>

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                    <li>link1</li>
                    <li>link2</li>
                    <li>link3</li>
                    <li>link4</li>
                    <li>link5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            
        <div id="body">
            <table id="tab">
                <tr>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>age</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                </tr>
        
                <tr>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td>xx</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- foot -->
        <h5 id="footer">Copyright xxx</h5>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I have add a js to see the width of the table,if you test it in the browser,you will get the size,the following is mine:

> Firefox:1062
>
> IE:1521.

So,I wonder why?

In my opinion,the result of Firefox is normal, why the table take more than the width of its parent (the div#body in the example)?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using a table? Divs are much more flexible for just about everything.

Comment: Your `div#body` doesn't have any width declaration, try setting one and see if that fixes it in IE. @Zydeco: It appears the OP is displaying tabular data, so it's an accepted use :)

Comment: @Kyle: Of course it is, if that's the case, but I see so many people still using tables for things other than what tables were meant for that it makes my skin crawl. ;)

Comment: @Zydeco: totally agreed, but you can tell in this case from context that it's used as purposed. Thankfully.

Comment: Sorry for my fault,the width of the table is 100%.

Comment: @Zydeco,I use table just for some tabual data,not for layout :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it actually works properly in IE.

Your table is going to get the width of the container which is the body.  It then gets 'pushed' over to the right by your menu  since you moved it over to the left by 190px.  This will make your total width 100% + 190px.

I would drop the margin-left on your div#body and just float it to the left.  Also you should stick with either fixed values or percentages.  Set the left column to 10% and the right column to 90% for example, and float them both to the left.

Comment: If I float the div#body,I can not make the content in div#body take all the width of the body. That's to say,I just want to make the table in the div#body take all the width of div#body.  Also,why firefox display normally?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/cj6fB/

Take a look at this and see if you can't change your layout a little to fit this.

The reason you're having issues with tables is because of browser specifications for tables. They're vastly different and there's no promised way to have a table fill 100% without knocking it around like that. I've played with it a bit and a table will always fill 100%, pushing it down below the menu instead of beside it.

I hope I've helped you a little even though I can't give you the answer that you wanted to hear.